# Apache Ant "SI command" for MKStask

Tags: apache, ant, command-line-interface, mks, mks-integrity

Upon trying to use the MKS task for apache ant, I need to specify the application executing the command. In the documentation I found, it says for example "si" or "im". I'm a little confused at this considered ant is used from command prompt so I'm not sure which application would be doing said command, nor do I know what applications "si" or "im" might be. I am using this task to try and send and receive build info to Integrity if that is pertinent. I was able to find this CLI reference guide for Integrity (link at bottom) which only uses im as a prefix, so I'm thinking that's the one I want to use, but I would appreciate an explanation as to what application im indicates (possible Integrity -something) and what one would specify with "si". Thanks

https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/attachment.cgi?id=52225

Answer (score 0):

The **si** commands are used for Source Integrity tasks (the SCCM side of things), while the **im** commands are used for Integrity Manager commands (the workflow and document management side of things).

The Integrity client should have man page support on all platforms, so you should be able to run **man im** or **man si** to see a breakdown of all the supported commands.

In addition, with newer releases of the client, pressing **F1** should get you a help interface, which includes documentation on CLI commands.

The guide to the link you posted is a very old version of the product CLI reference, and only for the **im** commands.

Since you're talking about using Ant, I'm assuming you're trying to perform builds, which will mostly involve **si** commands (creating sandboxes, checking out members, etc.).

Answer (score 0):

Here are a couple examples of using si in ant:

```
<target name="check.mks.conn">

    <echo message="Checking if an MKS connection exists. If not, one will be created." />

    <exec executable="si" failonerror="true">
      <arg line="connect" />
      <arg line="--hostname=${mks.server}" />
      <arg line="--port=${mks.port}" />
      <arg line="--user=${mks.user}" />
      <arg line="--gui" />
    </exec>

</target>


<!-- =================================================================== -->
<!-- If the sandbox already exists, resync the files                     -->
<!-- Manually drop any empty folders as resync does not do this.         -->
<!-- =================================================================== -->

<target name="resync.sandbox" unless="clean.build">
    <exec executable="si" failonerror="true">
      <arg line="resync" />
      <arg line="--hostname=${mks.server}" />
      <arg line="--port=${mks.port}" />
      <arg line="-R" />
      <arg line="-f" />
      <arg line="-Y" />
      <arg line="-S ${basedir}\${prj.name}\project.pj" />
    </exec>
    <delete includeemptydirs="true">
        <fileset dir="${prj.name}" excludes="**\*.*" />
    </delete>
</target>


<!-- =================================================================== -->
<!-- Drop and recreate the sandbox.                                      -->
<!-- =================================================================== -->

<target name="create.sandbox" if="clean.build" >
    <exec executable="si">
      <arg line="dropsandbox" />
      <arg line="--hostname=${mks.server}" />
      <arg line="--port=${mks.port}" />
      <arg line="--noconfirm" />
      <arg line="--batch" />
      <arg line='--delete=none' />
      <arg line="-Y" />
      <arg line="${basedir}\${prj.name}\project.pj" />
    </exec>
    <delete dir="${prj.name}" />
    <exec executable="si" resultproperty="createSBResult">
      <arg line="createsandbox" />
      <arg line="--hostname=${mks.server}" />
      <arg line="--port=${mks.port}" />
      <arg line="--project=c:/Projects/StoreWeb2/${prj.name}/project.pj" />
      <arg line="--projectRevision=${checkpoint.version}" />
      <arg line="--populate" />
      <arg line="--recurse" />
      <arg line="-Y" />
      <arg line="${basedir}\${prj.name}" />
    </exec>
    <!-- Check if the project is empty but for the mks system file project.pj -->
    <pathconvert property="is.project.not.empty" setonempty="false">
        <fileset dir="${prj.name}">
            <exclude name="project.pj"/>
        </fileset>
    </pathconvert>
    <condition property="try.mainline.storeweb">
      <not>
        <and>
          <equals arg1="0" arg2="${createSBResult}"/>
          <isset property="is.project.not.empty" />
        </and>
      </not>
    </condition>
    <antcall target="create.sandbox.mainline">
        <param name="prj.name" value="${prj.name}"/>
    </antcall>

</target>
```